# How to delete multiple keys in an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an array of objects which is looped and then deleting a set of key and values from it.I would like to know how to delete a set of keys with a single line if code instead of writing each delete for every key.

```
for (var i = 0; i < oldWorkers.length; i++) {
    delete oldWorkers[i].$$hashKey;
    delete oldWorkers[i].location;
    delete oldWorkers[i].name;
    delete oldWorkers[i].mobile_no;
    delete oldWorkers[i].type;
    LoadEntries.saveDaybook(oldWorkers[i]).then(
      function (resp) {
        proms.push(resp);
      },
      function (err) {
        CommonService.hideLoader();
        CommonService.toast(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: you can make a generic function to delete elements

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534602/javascript-built-in-function-to-delete-multiple-keys-in-an-object

Comment: you could re-group those value as a sub-object of oldWorkers[i] so you would just need to delete the sub-object itself.

Comment: `["$$hashKey","location","name","mobile_no","type"].forEach(key => { delete oldWorkers[i][key] })`

Comment: loop throgh the array and splice by index for eg : for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ data.splice(i)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't multiple delete via one statement, so some sort of iteration is required one way or another.

Declare a runtime array and iterate over it, perhaps.

```
['$$hashKey', 'location', 'name', 'mobile_no', 'type'].forEach(function(key) {
    delete oldWorkers[i][key];
});
```

Comment: How do I write something for deleting keys other than a list of keys?

Answer (score 6):

You can loop through keys and delete inside the callback

```
["$$hashKey", "location", "name", ".mobile_no", "type"].forEach(el => {delete oldWorkers[i][el];} )
```

Comment: I actually prefer your answer due to the nice ECMA6 syntax :)

Comment: I'm not the OP :) I'm the guy who did the accepted answer. But I've +1'd yours.