# React: How to delete multiple object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to delete multiple object properties with a one-liner in React?

I know about the `delete`-command: `delete obj.property` but since I'm deleting multiple numbers of object properties it would be nice to do this on one line instead of writing each time `delete obj.property` for every object that I'd like to delete.

Comment: asking for functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534602/javascript-built-in-function-to-delete-multiple-keys-in-an-object

Answer (score 3):

I mean you can create some helper function if its gonna be reuse throughout the code

```
function deleteProperties(target, properties){
   properties.forEach(item=>{
      delete target[item];
   })

}

const obj = {
option1: "KL",
option2: "AB",
option3: "CD"
}

deleteProperties(obj, ["option1", "option2"]);

console.log(obj)
```

Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/L1csragx/

or

```
["option1","option2"].forEach(item=> delete obj[item]);
```

Comment: Yes indeed, that was the other solution I was considering. I was just wondering whether there is a way to delete those object properties by using something a long the way of `delete obj["option1", "option2"]`. Would make it a lot easier and more parsimonious.

Comment: Fair point hmm but afaik I don't think there's a built in JS function that can delete multiple.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete multiple properties via one statement, so some sort of iteration is required one way or another. for example

```
['delete_key_1', 'delete_key_2'].forEach(function(key) {
    delete myObject[key];
});
```

Comment: ok, good to know - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**`

```js
const objec = {
option1: "KL",
option2: "AB",
option3: "CD"
}
let deleteingProp = ["option1","option2"]
for(let i of deleteingProp){
  delete objec[i]
}
```

`**