# Using generic types on array.reduce function to divide array into two

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, reduce

I was looking for a way to separate an array into 2 arrays given a validation function & found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731072/dividing-an-array-by-filter-function) that helped a lot.
The answer is the following:

```js
function partition(array, isValid) {
  return array.reduce(([pass, fail], elem) => {
    return isValid(elem) ? [[...pass, elem], fail] : [pass, [...fail, elem]];
  }, [[], []]);
}

const [pass, fail] = partition(myArray, (e) => e > 5);
```

Now I want to write the same question but now using typescript:

```html
      const separateArray = <T>(array: T[], condition: (e: T) => boolean): [T[], T[]] => {
        return array.reduce(([passed, failed], elem: T) => condition(elem) ? [
          [...passed, elem], failed
        ] : [passed, [...failed, elem]],[[],[]])
      }
```

The above works just fine, the thing is that when I try to set the type for the first param of the `reduce` function TO `[T[], T[]]` I get an error:

**Code:**

```
    return array.reduce(([passed, failed]: [T[], T[]] ......
```

**Error:**

```
Type 'T[][]' is not assignable to type '[T[], T[]]'.
  Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.
```

I tried setting the type to `[any[],any[]]` and `[any, any]` but I still get the same error.

Does anyone know how can I solve this?

Comment: Do not be afraid of a little bit of type assertion when justified, especially for initially empty arrays. I do not know if you are able to see @Crice 's deleted answer, but it seems to me as a totally valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is inferring the type of the first parameter as `T[][]` based on the return value in the conditional operation: `[[…passed, elem], failed]` and so on since type of either `passed` or `failed` isn’t defined and `elem` has type `T`. You can tell typescript explicitly that the type is `[T[], T[]]` instead.

```
const separateArray = <T>(array: T[], condition: (e: T) => boolean): [T[], T[]] => {
    return array.reduce(([passed, failed]: [T[], T[]], elem: T) => condition(elem) ? [
      [...passed, elem], failed
        ] as [T[], T[]]: [passed, [...failed, elem]] as [T[], T[]],[[],[]])
  }
```

Comment: In case @CRice does not undelete their answer: the above answer can be improved by type asserting directly the initial value, instead of having to it 3 times (the argument and the 2 possible returns).