# How to group by property in an array of objs in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, boolean

##### ⛰️ Hi community,

I need to group an array of objs by their boolean

##### Data

In these simplify example i have data (an array of objs) where every objet has a boolean and i need to group it by the information in the boolean.

- "R" = Right
- "L" = Left

##### Data

```
 const data = 
   [
    {id: 3337, score: 75, date: '2000-02-02T07:25:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4337, score: 65, date: '2000-02-02T07:25:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 3336, score: 30, date: '2012-06-02T08:24:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4336, score: 32, date: '2012-06-02T08:24:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 3335, score: 25, date: '2020-08-02T09:23:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4335, score: 30, date: '2020-08-02T09:23:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 2234, score: 85, date: '2018-08-02T12:20:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4234, score: 80, date: '2018-08-02T12:20:12.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 1534, score: 85, date: '2016-08-02T10:30:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4534, score: 88, date: '2016-08-02T10:30:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 3884, score: 85, date: '2019-08-02T11:18:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4884, score: 79, date: '2019-08-02T11:18:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 6534, score: 25, date: '2012-08-02T13:01:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4534, score: 22, date: '2012-08-02T13:05:00.000Z', boolean: "L"}
   ],
```

##### Expected Output

```
 const result =
 [
   [
    {id: 3337, score: 75, date: '2000-02-02T07:25:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 3336, score: 30, date: '2012-06-02T08:24:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 3335, score: 25, date: '2020-08-02T09:23:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 2234, score: 85, date: '2018-08-02T12:20:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 1534, score: 85, date: '2016-08-02T10:30:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 3884, score: 85, date: '2019-08-02T11:18:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 6534, score: 25, date: '2012-08-02T13:01:00.000Z', boolean: "R"}
   ],
   [
    {id: 4337, score: 65, date: '2000-02-02T07:25:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 4336, score: 32, date: '2012-06-02T08:24:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 4335, score: 30, date: '2020-08-02T09:23:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 4234, score: 80, date: '2018-08-02T12:20:12.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 4534, score: 88, date: '2016-08-02T10:30:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 4884, score: 79, date: '2019-08-02T11:18:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 4534, score: 22, date: '2012-08-02T13:05:00.000Z', boolean: "L"}
   ]
 ]
```

I think the answer would be with a map, sort it out and the push it, right? . But i don't have any clue how to do it.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: also: [Dividing an array by filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731072/dividing-an-array-by-filter-function)

Comment: @mplungjan regardless it is a duplicate many times over, and I'd probably use a `for...of` and avoid the multiple filter calls.

Comment: `const result = [[],[]]; const test = ["L","R"]; data.forEach(item => result[test.findIndex(t => t === item.boolean)].push(item));` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array.forEach() and test the value of your boolean, then put it in an array accordingly.

```js
const result = [
   [],
   []    
]

data.forEach(row => {
    if(row.boolean === "L") result[0].push(row);
    if(row.boolean === "R") result[1].push(row);
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>

const data = 
   [
    {id: 3337, score: 75, date: '2000-02-02T07:25:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4337, score: 65, date: '2000-02-02T07:25:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 3336, score: 30, date: '2012-06-02T08:24:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4336, score: 32, date: '2012-06-02T08:24:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 3335, score: 25, date: '2020-08-02T09:23:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4335, score: 30, date: '2020-08-02T09:23:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 2234, score: 85, date: '2018-08-02T12:20:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4234, score: 80, date: '2018-08-02T12:20:12.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 1534, score: 85, date: '2016-08-02T10:30:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4534, score: 88, date: '2016-08-02T10:30:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 3884, score: 85, date: '2019-08-02T11:18:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4884, score: 79, date: '2019-08-02T11:18:15.000Z', boolean: "L"},
    {id: 6534, score: 25, date: '2012-08-02T13:01:00.000Z', boolean: "R"},
    {id: 4534, score: 22, date: '2012-08-02T13:05:00.000Z', boolean: "L"}
   ]
</script>
```

Comment: Cool thanks a lot @Arthur.. I have a question in your code. Why do put row.boolean or push(row).. what is row?

Comment: the forEach statement allows you to loop over each element of your array, and apply a function to each of these elements. This function takes a parameter (the current element of the array). I named it row. It is equivalent to for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { row = data[i]; ... } !