# Return filtered array and also elements that were removed in one-go

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get the result of `filter()` but also the elements that were removed in the process. For example, I want to get `[1]` as a result of the normal `filter` operation as well as `[2, 3]` in the following execution:

```
[1, 2, 3].filter(num => num <= 1)
```

Currently, I'm doing it like this - is there a better and faster way?

```js
function filter() {
  const removedNumbers = [];

  const newArray = [1, 2, 3].filter((num) => {
    if (num > 1) {
      removedNumbers.push(num);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });

  return {
    newArray,
    removedNumbers,
  };
}
console.log(filter())
```

Comment: Related: [Dividing an array by filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11731072) (this has other solutions)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy), but be aware of its [coverage](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_groupby).

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];
const { true: filtered, false: removed } = Object.groupBy(array, e => e > 1);

console.log({ filtered, removed });
```

Comment: Very elegant...

Comment: This would make a good answer on: [Dividing an array by filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11731072)

Comment: I agree, @Hao, please post it there so we can close this as a dupe

Comment: @NickParsons Indeed, I just posted an answer on that question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array::reduce()`, seems faster than `Object.groupBy()`.

There's a known problem with the new `flatMap()` that it uses iterators and notoriously slower exactly known 6.2x times.

Seems a similar fate befell `Object.groupBy()`:

```js
const [filtered, removed] = [1,2,3].reduce((r, num) => (r[+(num <= 1)].push(num), r), [[],[]]);
console.log({filtered, removed});
```

```
` Chrome/122
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                        n=100      |     n=1000     |    n=10000    |    n=100000   
Array::reduce()     1.00x   x1m 490 | 1.00x x10k 146 | 1.00x x1k 180 | 1.00x x100 227
Object.groupBy();   3.61x x100k 177 | 1.25x x10k 183 | 1.08x x1k 195 | 1.62x x100 368
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const $chunk = () => Array.from({length:100}, () => Math.random()*2);
const $input = [];

// @benchmark Object.groupBy();
const { true: filtered, false: removed } = Object.groupBy($input, e => e > 1);
({filtered, removed});

// @benchmark Array::reduce()
{
const [filtered, removed] = $input.reduce((r, num) => (r[+(num <= 1)].push(num), r), [[],[]]);
({filtered, removed});
}

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));
```